# Strange pow implementation in golang

Tags: go

I just came across [the Pow implementation in golang](https://golang.org/src/math/pow.go):

```
func Pow(x, y float64) float64 {
    // ...
    case x == 0:
        switch {
        case y < 0:
            if isOddInt(y) {
                return Copysign(Inf(1), x)
            }
            return Inf(1)
        case y > 0:
            if isOddInt(y) {
                return x
            }
            return 0
        }
    //...
}
```

Isn't the `case y > 0` part over complicated? I would just return 0.  Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two types of zero's, `+0` and `-0`. return value of `Pow(-0,1)` should be `-0` not `+0`

to create `-0` in golang, use `math.Copysign`.

```
x := math.Copysign(0, -1)
if x == 0 {
    fmt.Println("x is zero")
}
fmt.Println("x ** 3 is", math.Pow(x, 3))
```

the output of above code is

```
x is zero
x ** 3 is -0
```

you can check it in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8wuZ0EUSgD)

why we have to distinguish `+0` and `-0`, see:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280648/why-is-negative-zero-important

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the inline documentation for the function, in the case case `y > 0` then the function output is as follows:

```
Pow(±0, y) = ±0 for y an odd integer > 0
Pow(±0, y) = +0 for finite y > 0 and not an odd integer
```

so the function will only return `0` `(+0)` like you say in the case that `x=0`